# How do you monitor auto scaling on AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I setup a quick web app using the Visual Studio Toolkit and deployed it to CloudFormation with the default settings.  I then started to load the app using JMeter until eventually it stopped returning 200 statuses.

From what I can see no auto scaling has occurred - ie: no duplicate instances have been started up.  Is this something that needs to be configured manually in CloudWatch with an alarm based on CPU usage or is CloudFormation handling this for me?

Comment: Hi, you mention CloudFormation in your question, but you have the elastic-beanstalk tag.  Can you confirm if you are using Elastic Beanstalk or CloudFormation?  If CloudFormation, are you using the load balanced template?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading tag - it was CloudFormation with load balancing specified in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I made a mistake - after further testing I found that the load balancer did scale after it hit a certain threshold of kb out per second. I think the issue was that I hit it way to hard initially and it just tanked before it had a chance to scale.